# DAX Lookupvalue

Tags: powerbi, dax

I've searched and searched.

I have a table with Zip code, city, county, state.

I have another table that I want the zip code to populate based upon the city column and the state column.

The tables are unrelated and I have been able to populate the state using Lookupvalue

[City, State, Zip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hx681.png)

Since states have cities with common names (Arlington, VA vs. Arlington, TX), I'm trying to use Lookupvalue to find the zip by city then by state.  So the attached image would go:

Zip Code 2 =
LOOKUPVALUE('Current States Single County'[zip],'Current States Single County'[city], 'Zip Code_retest'[city],'Current States Single County'[state],'Zip Code_retest'[statename])

But I get the "A table of multiple values was supplied where a single value was expected error."

Can Lookupvalue perform this?  The code looks like I should be able to put multiple criteria.  If not, what is recommended?

Thanks.

Comment: DAX is a wrong tool for such tasks. Use PowerQuery, or better yet, prepare your data in a database before importing it into PBI.

Comment: I think you need to give more information here. What is the full error message? I also agree with @RADO that you should do this data enrichment in ETL and not after the tables are loaded into the data model.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use your LOOKUPVALUE expression as a **calculated column** and not as a **measure** since the formula requires a **row context**.

Comment: I don't understand the column would be "Zip Code =  LOOKUPVALUE('Current States Single County'[zip],'Current States Single County'[city], 'Zip Code_retest'[city],'Current States Single County'[state],'Zip Code_retest'[statename])"...is that not a calculated column

Comment: Can't judge since you are not revealing enough information about your data model. But if you are actually using a calculated column, the error is likely caused by duplicate values.

Comment: The image shows a Power BI table view, so it is probably a calculated column.